# How do I extract an item number that looks roughly like 95E10 from a string using ruby regex

Tags: regex, ruby, data-extraction

Given strings that look like one of the two following

"Stop Blasting to Move Track, Continue Blasting 95E10 FF"

"Continue Blasting I.D. on Exchanger 95HE03A"

how can I used ruby regex to extract item numbers 95E10 and 95HE03A respectively?

Comment: This cannot be answered without you providing the rule for determining whether a substring is to be returned. For example, is the rule to return all strings that contain digits and uppercase letters and begin with "95"? Or perhaps the rule is all of the foregoing requirements but the string also must contain an "E". You can ask readers how the rule can be implemented but not what the rule should be.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
\d+(([A-Z]+)?(\d+)?)*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OxOYSk/1

---

https://rubular.com/
[image]

Comment: ++ though may I suggest adding a brief summary about the regex used instead of rubular screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
\d+[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*
```

## Explanation

The `\d+`'s match the numbers on either side of the string. `[A-Z]` in the middle matches the letters in the middle, whilst the `[A-Z]*` matches zero or more letters at the end.

Comment: You are too kind. It worked wonderfully.

Comment: I have a follow-up. Suppose it is a single string "Stop Blasting to Move Track, Continue Blasting 95E10 FF & continue Blasting I.D. on Exchanger 95HE03A" and I want to extract the item numbers parsing the former item number as an "FF" and the latter as an "Exchanger"?